# Как реализовать данный эффект в блоке?

Tags: css3, css-animation

[image: пример]

День добрый. 
Есть задача.
Даны 3 блока. Каждый из них будет реализован элементами списка в обертке блока с днем. 
Задача такова. 
Блок изначально с голубым фоном.
Если длина контента будет больше чем ширина блока - к нему необходимо добавить белый градиент, который будет смягчать эффект выхода контента за блок.
Если длина контента будет меньше или равной ширине блока. Никакого градиента быть не должно.

Был предложен вариант реализации на js. Отловка ширины блока и контента, сравнение и потом добавление псевдокласса по необходимости.

Есть ли какие то варианты сделать это на css?

Comment: От Javascript не стоит отказываться)) ведь вилкой хлебать суп - не лучший вариант :)

Answer (score 1):

Прошло почти два года, как был задан вопрос, но что-то никто не спешит отвечать, исходя из меток и пожеланий автора вопроса. А, между тем, время идёт и появляются новые возможности в браузерах. Не стоит на месте и CSS...

### Overflow:hidden & position:absolute - Проблема, которая помогла

Часто начинающие (да и уже бывалые) верстальщики сталкиваются с проблемой - пытаются "подружить" `overflow:hidden` родительского блока с `position:absolute` вложенных в него элементов (например, показ полной строки, при наведении). Конечно же, такие попытки заканчиваются провалом, не смотря на различные ухищрения (на самом деле, тут только JS в помощь, но в итоге выглядит ужасно). *На "костылях" по "граблям" далеко не уйдёшь.*

Как оказалось, при правильном подходе и применении, такое поведение является плюсом, а может и единственным решением определённых задач, и в ответе используется именно оно:

```css
:root { --cell-width: 37vw; }

.cell {
  font: 14px 'Arial';
  width: var(--cell-width);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cell * { box-sizing: border-box; }

.first_line { display: flex; padding: 0.5em; height: 2em; }
.date { flex: 1; }
.more { text-decoration: none; }

.task {
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: #e5effc;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}
.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
}
.wbr {
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.wbr:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: calc(var(--cell-width) - 25px);
  height: 2em;
  width: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #fff 85%);
}

input { width: var(--cell-width); margin: 1em auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div class="first_line"><span class="date">13</span><a href="#" class="more">+ещё 3</a></div>
  <div class="task"><span class="text">Мобильный трафик для проекта</span><span class="wbr"></span></div>
  <div class="task"><span class="text">Таргетированная реклама</span><span class="wbr"></span></div>
  <div class="task"><span class="text">Работа с базой клиентов</span><span class="wbr"></span></div>
  <div class="task"><span class="text">Попробуйте изменить размер окна</span><span class="wbr"></span></div>
</div>

<input oninput="document.querySelector('div.cell>div:nth-child(2)>span.text').innerText = this.value;" placeholder="Вводите текст различной длины">
```

Появление и поддержка CSS-переменных (`var(--var)`) позволили добавить адаптивности. Хотя, если ячейки будут неизменной ширины, то переменные можно заменить на абсолютные значения, расширив тем самым поддержку в сторону более старых браузеров.

Answer (score 0):

Без js не обойтись - в css нет специального селектора вида "выходит ли текст за рамки".

Вы можете добавить небольшие по ширине псевдоэлементы с градиентами в CSS. Тогда длинный текст будет "затухать", как требуется, а короткий будет виден в блоке без затухания просто потому что не будет доставать до градиента. Неприятно затухать будет только текст, практически до конца подходящий к правому краю.

В любом случае - в js это решается простым и небольшим скриптом:

```
var updateOverflowedItems = function() {
  $items = $('.item')
  if ($items.length) {
    $items.each(function() {
      $item = $(this);
      if ($item[0].scrollWidth >  $item.innerWidth()) {
        $item.addClass('item_overflowed');
      } else {
        $item.removeClass('item_overflowed');
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(updateOverflowedItems);
```

Где `($item[0].scrollWidth >  $item.innerWidth())` - определение вышедшего за пределы блока текста.

```js
var updateOverflowedItems = function() {
  $items = $('.item')
  if ($items.length) {
    $items.each(function() {
      $item = $(this);
      if ($item[0].scrollWidth >  $item.innerWidth()) {
        $item.addClass('item_overflowed');
      } else {
        $item.removeClass('item_overflowed');
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(updateOverflowedItems);
```

```css
.items {
  width: 200px;  
}

.item {
  background: #e3ecfb;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #ccd8ef;
}

.item_overflowed::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #e3ecfb 100%);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.item_overflowed:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #ccd8ef 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Мобильный трафик для проекта</div>
  <div class="item">Таргетированная реклама</div>
  <div class="item">Работа с базой клиентов</div>
</div>
```

[Или посмотреть пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/dzh8dgy4/).

Или то же самое - без jQuery:

```js
this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateOverflowedItems, true);

function updateOverflowedItems(e) {
  items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  if (items) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(item, index) {
      if (item.scrollWidth > item.clientWidth) {
        item.classList.add('item_overflowed');
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('item_overflowed');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.items {
  width: 200px;  
}

.item {
  background: #e3ecfb;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #ccd8ef;
}

.item_overflowed::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #e3ecfb 100%);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.item_overflowed:hover::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #ccd8ef 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Мобильный трафик для проекта</div>
  <div class="item">Таргетированная реклама</div>
  <div class="item">Работа с базой клиентов</div>
</div>
```